# delete/hide file from itunes library used in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, itunes

I have made an iphone application in which i am getting songs from itunes library and display in table as well as store them in my document directory. Now i want to make it secret..So i want to delete the selected file from itunes library so it wont be displayed in list. Can anyone help me to do this??
Code:

```
importableDoc = [NSMutableArray array];
// Get public docs dir
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *publicDocumentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];   

// Get contents of documents directory
NSError *error;
NSArray *files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:publicDocumentsDir error:&error];
if (files == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading contents of documents directory: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

// Add all mp3 files to a list    

for (NSString *file in files) {
    if ([file.pathExtension compare:@"mp3" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) 
    {        

        NSString *fullPath = [publicDocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
                //NSLog(@"fullPath : %@",fullPath);

        [importableDoc addObject:fullPath];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but it looks like you're out of luck. From [Media Player Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html):

> The Media Player framework provides facilities for playing movie,
>   music, audio podcast, and audio book files. This framework also gives
>   your application access to the iPod library, letting you find and play
>   audio-based media items synced from iTunes on the desktop. **iPod
>   library access is read-only**.

As an alternative, instead of using a `MPMediaPickerController` you could use `MPMediaQueries` to display your own custom list of songs available, but that still doesn't give you to opportunity to actually remove tracks from the users iPod library.

Comment: Thanks. But i have resolved this issue by another way. I am saving the songs into DocumentLibrary and remove from document directory..Means i am saving the songs in both document directory as well as selected song will be stored in library and will be deleted from document directory.Thanks again for your answer. :)